# Is my software developing architecture not good

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, model-view-controller

For my company, I have developed one winform application, that handles Unified COmmunication. 
It's been 1 year in development. I Just write global functions in seperate classes, and write the code in either form or class. Now They wanted me to make three seperate copies(UI of each changed) of the same Software. I have changed all UI and everything needed, and made 3 copies. But now, I feel it very difficult to correct any issues, or add any features. I have to change it in my all three copies. How can I solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to seperate the logic from the visual parts and make all 3 versions use the same logic.dll. That way you only have to maintain 3 different visuals. In general, seperation is a good idea.

Comment: I have written everything under form code-behind. Is it a bad practice ?

Comment: Yes. You are currently expiriencing why.

Comment: I think, if i had made this as like ur first comment, the problem might have solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume the three versions are very similar. First off, it's of the utmost importance that you keep your project under source control.

Personally, I would have created a `dev` branch for the main version, and then create two other branches for the 2 other versions (e.g., `dev-v1` and `dev-v2`), created off the main branch.

Then, whenever I had to apply a patch to all 3 versions, I'd do it on the `dev` branch, and then merge `dev` with `dev-v1` and again with `dev-v2`.

So far I only addressed the source control issue, but as CSharpie pointed out in the comments, you should definitely separate the presentation layer (i.e., forms) from the business logic. Furthermore, these two should also be separated from the data layer.
Take a look at [Multitier architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Separation doesn't necessarily mean different projects or solutions. Having a logical separation (e.g., having sets of classes with very well defined purposes, following the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) etc.) is often enough. In your case, however, it seems that the presentation layer should be in a different project than the other two.

Comment: yes we do, using stash. But Is it good doing all the codes in form itself ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses I've edited my answer to address that issue.